# How to set Min and Max Date in Jquery Date Selection depending on current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

The JSFiddle Can be Found Here: http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/682/

I need it to:
Pick a date in a 365 day period based on user selection input. For example is a user inputs 01/01/2016, they can only select a date between 01/01/2016 and 01/01/2017 and nothing after that.

I have also set a method where if the date is before 31st Jan the minimum the start and end date can vary. For example the only dates a user can choose from are 31/01/2015 - 31/12/2016

```
var d = new Date(); var Month = d.getMonth();var Month = Month + 1;
var Year = d.getFullYear(); var Day = d.getDate();

if(Day <= 9){ var Day = "0".concat(Day);}  

if(Month <= 9){ var Month = "0".concat(Month);}  

if(Month == 01 && Day <= 31){
var Year = Year - 1;
var MinYear = "31-01-"+Year;
var Year = Year + 1;
var MaxYear = "31-12-"+Year;
} else { 
var MinYear = "31-01-"+Year;
var Year = Year + 1;
var MaxYear = "31-12-"+Year;
} 

$(function() {

     /* global setting */
    var datepickersOpt = {
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate   : 0
    }

    $("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker($.extend({
        onSelect: function() {
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()-365); //add two days
            $("#TxtExpDte").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minDate);
        }
    },datepickersOpt));

    $("#TxtExpDte").datepicker($.extend({
        onSelect: function() {
            var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()+365);
            $("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate);
        }
    },datepickersOpt));
});
```

Comment: `minDate` and `maxDate` both accept relative values … http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Answer (score 2):

Based on your JSFiddle example:

```
var datepickersOpt = {
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate   : 0
}

$("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker($.extend({
    onSelect: function() {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var maxDate = new Date();

        $('#TxtExpDte').datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);

        // add 365 days to the selected date
        maxDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 365); 
        $("#TxtExpDte").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate);
    }
},datepickersOpt));

$("#TxtExpDte").datepicker($.extend({},datepickersOpt));
```

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2op64ytL/1/

Result:

[image]